# uglifying underscore breaks sourcemaps during browserify

Tags: node.js, underscore.js, browserify, uglifyjs, source-maps

[Related, but unanswered.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055660/browserify-source-map-not-working-if-require-underscore)

In my NPM project, I have the following folder `public`:

```
sourcemaps $ tree public/
public/
├── index.html
├── js
    ├── bar.js
    ├── foo.js
    ├── main.js
```

In `bar`:

```
'use strict';

var go = module.exports = function () {
  return 'hey, I am bar';    
};
```

In `foo`:

```
'use strict';

var bar = require('./bar');

var go = module.exports = function () {
  console.log(bar());  
};
```

In `main`:

```
'use strict';

var foo = require('./foo');

foo();
```

I have a node script that uglifies and creates sourcemaps:

```
var bundle_map = 'public/js/bundle-map.json'
  , stream = ''
  , browserify = require('browserify')
  , exorcist = require('exorcist')
  , uglifyjs = require('uglify-js')
  , fs = require('fs');

browserify({entries: 'public/js/main.js', debug: true})
.bundle()
.pipe(exorcist(bundle_map))
.on('data', function(chunk) {
  stream += chunk;
})
.on('end', function() {
  var minified = uglifyjs.minify(stream, {
    fromString: true,
    inSourceMap: bundle_map,
    outSourceMap: 'bundle-min.map'
  });

  fs.writeFile('public/js/bundle-min.js', minified.code);
  fs.writeFile('public/js/bundle-min.map', JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(minified.map)));
});
```

`index`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/bundle-min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the source maps fine when serving the site through [Rack::Static](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Static). Here's `config.ru`:

```
use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/js"], :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

But when I `npm install underscore` in the `sourcemaps` directory, I don't get source maps.

Does anyone know why this happens? I don't get any errors in the Chrome console, either, and I see the source maps downloading fine in both cases:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2015 19:26:55] "GET /js/bundle-min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0003
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2015 19:26:55] "GET /js/bundle-min.map HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0003
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2015 19:26:55] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0005
```

Requiring other node modules (`react`, e.g., or `exorcist`) and leaving `underscore` out gets me the source maps in Chrome Developer tools just fine.

Also, taking `uglify-js` out of the stream pipeline but leaving `underscore` in gives me the right sourcemaps! Hm...

Answer (score 0):

having the same issue but without browserify, I'm simply trying to concat multiple files together with gulp then uglify them and generate a sourcemap. And I just found out that if I take underscore out of the equation it work, but if I leave underscore the source map won't work.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to serve files with an HTTP server to reproduce the issue, btw. I'll distill my example when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the part of underscore that cause the problem, just not sure what would fix it.

it's this part of the _.template(); function :

```
source += text.slice(index, offset).replace(escaper, escapeChar);
```

seem like valid code, I don't get it.

Comment: Cool, great job! Does commenting that line out work? I'm not sure if this is an underscore bug, or an uglify-js bug.

Comment: yeah, on my side just commenting that single line is the difference between the source map not showing in chrome and it showing up.

It broke my app, because I use the underscore template thing somewhere in my app tho.

I'm really not sure whether it's a underscore or uglify bug.. it look like valid js.

At first I thought it was the line under it that was the cause, and that would have clearly been an uglify bug. But now I don't know what to think.

Comment: the next line is -> source += "'+\n((__t=(" + escape + "))==null?'':_.escape(__t))+\n'";

Comment: I would have understand why Uglify would not like that line lol

Comment: I just tried using the last version of underscore to be sure. Because my current version is the previous version that I heavily striped out to reduce the size. And yeah same thing, commenting that single line fix the problem.

Comment: I think this would make sense as a bug to submit to uglify-js, and link to this question? Are you using uglify-js, or another minifier? Do you have a minimal test case?

Comment: I'm using gulp-uglify who is using uglify-js. No I don't have the time right now to do a test case. I might make one this week-end, i'll let you know.

Comment: I just got this to work using minifyify, disabling caching while dev-tools is open and clearing the browser cache. I can see the sourcemaps when served through HTTP or the filesystem.

Does this work for you? If so, I'm going to use this as the accepted answer.

Comment: nope, I don't use browserify, only gulp. So minifyify is not an option for me. Clearing the cache don't work. But you can close this issue if it work for your problem. I will continue my quest to get this fixed on my own. Glad you figured out how to make it work for you :)

Comment: basically this -> http://pastebin.com/U3U9Yp2X

it's not my real file, there way more to it, but that's the part that don't work. I have almost the same thing in another folder without underscore and it work perfectly. I got one file at the end that has a sourcemap that tell chrome that it's 5 js separated files inside one bundle and chrome show them to me as multiple separate file instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using [minifyify](https://github.com/ben-ng/minifyify), disabling caching while dev-tools is open and clearing the browser cache. I also got it to work using [gulp-sourcemaps](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps).

I can see the sourcemaps when served through HTTP or the filesystem. Does this work for you? If so, I'm going to use this as the accepted answer.

Here's the code snippet with `minifyify`:

```
gulp.task 'bundle', (done) ->
  browserify(entries: DEST.js('grid.js'), debug: true)
    .plugin 'minifyify',
      map: 'bundle-min.map'
      output: 'public/js/bundle-min.map'
    .bundle (err, src, map) ->
      fs.writeFile DEST.js('bundle-min.js'), src
      done?()
```

And using `gulp-sourcemaps`:
    buffer = require 'vinyl-buffer'
    source = require 'vinyl-source-stream'
    uglify = require 'gulp-uglify'
    sourcemaps = require 'gulp-sourcemaps'

```
gulp.task 'bundle', (done) ->
  browserify(entries: DEST.js('grid.js'), debug: true)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(exorcist(DEST.js('bundle-min.js.map')))
    .pipe(source(DEST.js('bundle-min.js')))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init(loadMaps: true))
      .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
```

I read through their source code a bit to try and see what they're doing right and what I was doing wrong, but ultimately I just want to start writing my app :).